# $hook['display_override'][] not working in CodeIgniter 1.72

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, optimization

CodeIgniter 1.7.2 version and I am very strange that hook ==> display_override not working.

I tested the other hooks ==> pre_controller, post_controller that was working prefect but only problem with this hook ==> display_override not working.

I tested this hook to insert die() in callback function of hook that not calling. (callback function output() )

I am working on HTML optimization as below. please any idea

## Directory:

1) 
application/config/config.php

```
$config['enable_hooks'] = TRUE;
```

========================================
2) 
application/config/hooks.php

```
$hook['display_override'][] = array(
    'class' => 'Minifyhtml',
    'function' => 'output',
    'filename' => 'Minifyhtml.php',
    'filepath' => 'hooks',
    'params' => array()
);
```

=============================================

3) 
application/hooks/Minifyhtml.php

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

/**
 * Minifyhtml Class
 * Will Minify the HTML. Reducing network latency, enhancing compression, and faster browser loading and execution.
 * 
 * @category    Output
 * @author      John Gerome
 * @link        https://github.com/johngerome/CodeIgniter-Minifyhtml-hooks
 */

class Minifyhtml {

    /**
     * Responsible for sending final output to browser
     */

    function output()
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();
        $buffer = $CI->output->get_output();
        $re = '%            # Collapse ws everywhere but in blacklisted elements.
            (?>             # Match all whitespans other than single space.
              [^\S ]\s*     # Either one [\t\r\n\f\v] and zero or more ws,
            | \s{2,}        # or two or more consecutive-any-whitespace.
            ) # Note: The remaining regex consumes no text at all...
            (?=             # Ensure we are not in a blacklist tag.
              (?:           # Begin (unnecessary) group.
                (?:         # Zero or more of...
                  [^<]++    # Either one or more non-"<"
                | <         # or a < starting a non-blacklist tag.
                  (?!/?(?:textarea|pre)\b)
                )*+         # (This could be "unroll-the-loop"ified.)
              )             # End (unnecessary) group.
              (?:           # Begin alternation group.
                <           # Either a blacklist start tag.
                (?>textarea|pre)\b
              | \z          # or end of file.
              )             # End alternation group.
            )  # If we made it here, we are not in a blacklist tag.
            %ix';
        $buffer = preg_replace($re, " ", $buffer);
        $CI->output->set_output($buffer);
        $CI->output->_display();
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hight time to use CodeIgniter 3 version.

In your exemple perhaps exist extra brackets []
Try this code:

```
$hook['display_override'] = ...
```